# Can you get your Twitter email using the API?

Tags: ios, api, authentication, twitter

I am developing a iOS App and I have login with Facebook, LinkedIn, Google+ and **Twitter**.
All of them let me read my email from my profile using API, **EXCEPT** Twitter.

Is there any way to get **my email**?

If not, is there in twitter a "internal email", a generated email like in facebook (someone@facebook.com)?

The reason is that I use email as identifier (primary key) for users in my database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, email address are not available via the Twitter API: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1737

Nor is there any "internal email" available, you will have to use the twitter username and ask the user fro there e-mail address.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use *Twitter framework*. Twitter has provided a beautiful framework for that, you just have to integrate it in your app.

To get user email address, your application should be whitelisted. Here is the [link](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/request-email). Go to [use this form](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform). You can either send mail to sdk-feedback@twitter.com with some details about your App like Consumer key, App Store link of an App, Link to privacy policy, Metadata, Instructions on how to log into our App etc..They will respond within 2-3 working days.

Here is the story how I got whitelisted by conversation with Twitter support team:

- Send mail to `sdk-feedback@twitter.com` with some details about your App like Consumer key, App Store link of an App, Link to privacy policy, Metadata, Instructions on how to log into our App. Mention in mail that you want to access user email adress inside your App.
- They will review your App and reply to you withing 2-3 business days.
- Once they say that your App is whitelisted, update your App's settings in Twitter Developer portal. Sign in to [apps.twitter.com](http://apps.twitter.com) and:

  1. On the 'Settings' tab, add a terms of service and privacy policy URL
  2. On the 'Permissions' tab, change your token's scope to request email. This option will only been seen, once your App gets whitelisted.

## Put your hands on code

Use of Twitter framework:

**Get user email address**

```
-(void)requestUserEmail
    {
        if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {

            TWTRShareEmailViewController *shareEmailViewController =
            [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc]
             initWithCompletion:^(NSString *email, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Email %@ | Error: %@", email, error);
             }];

            [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController
                               animated:YES
                             completion:nil];
        } else {
            // Handle user not signed in (e.g. attempt to log in or show an alert)
        }
    }
```

**Get user profile**

```
-(void)usersShow:(NSString *)userID
{
    NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json";
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"user_id": userID};

    NSError *clientError;
    NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
                             URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET"
                             URL:statusesShowEndpoint
                             parameters:params
                             error:&clientError];

    if (request) {
        [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
         sendTwitterRequest:request
         completion:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                      NSData *data,
                      NSError *connectionError) {
             if (data) {
                 // handle the response data e.g.
                 NSError *jsonError;
                 NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:data
                                       options:0
                                       error:&jsonError];
                 NSLog(@"%@",[json description]);
             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"Error code: %ld | Error description: %@", (long)[connectionError code], [connectionError localizedDescription]);
             }
         }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !!!