# Whitelisted ios app by Twitter still not getting email of user

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I have had my iOS app whitelisted by Twitter but I am still not getting email of user.

What else do I need to do to get email id?

I read https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials but, is it useful in iOS app for Twitter integration?

Getting below error:

> Error Domain=TwitterAPIErrorDomain Code=37 "Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform." UserInfo=0x7fa3cb9e0df0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Your application may not have access to email addresses or the user may not have an email address. To request access, please visit https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.}

Here is my code:

```
-(void)requestUserEmail
{
    if ([[Twitter sharedInstance] session]) {

        TWTRShareEmailViewController *shareEmailViewController =
        [[TWTRShareEmailViewController alloc]
         initWithCompletion:^(NSString *email, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Email %@ | Error: %@", email, error);
         }];

        [self presentViewController:shareEmailViewController
                           animated:YES
                         completion:nil];
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

after a conversation with Twitter support team, they recommend to:

`Do a "clean project" to make sure all cached information is gone.`

Also make sure you are using the right keys for the specific whitelisted App

Comment: I clean project even deleted and reinstall again...but no use. what do you mean exactly "Also make sure you are using the right keys for the specific whitelisted App", I am using fabric.

Comment: what i was doing wrong in my app is that i was using fabric with keys from a different app than the one whitelisted by twitter, please check your app code and look for Consumer Key (API Key) and Consumer Secret (API Secret) and make sure they are the one whitelisted by twitter.

Comment: @MounirElfassi My fabric consumer key and secret key and of twitter are different. Fabric keys are not editable so how to change it can you please guide.

Comment: i think Fabric keys are editable, just post your question with more details i'll be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to request Twitter team to white-list your App. After having some conversation on mail, you will be able to get white-listed.

Please refer to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845028/get-my-twitter-email/30507329#30507329).

Comment: Did you get mail from Twitter team saying that your App has been whitelisted ?

Comment: As I stated in my subject line My app is already Whitelisted by Twitter (got email from twitter stated that they whitelist my app and also after that I enable setting in my twitter developer app account. ) ...But still not getting email? Do I need to do extra?

Comment: Did you check this: (1) On the 'Settings' tab, add a terms of service and privacy policy URL. (2) On the 'Permissions' tab, change your token's scope to request email. This option will only been seen, once your App gets whitelisted.

Comment: Check the API keys provided for your App. If still issue, you can contact the support team of Twitter..

Comment: I had followed steps provided by the twitter team and I could able to get the mail of logged in user. I don't know what's wrong happening in your case..

Comment: can you provide me the steps from 1st to last might be I am missing something I am using Twitter and fabric